# content query webpart, show document libraries items only

Tags: development

The following code adds a cqwp, and it works almost fine.  When I go to design view, the type is Assets Library instead of Document Library.

What am I missing here?

```
#region Last updated documents
                                ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                                cqwp.BaseType = "1";
                                cqwp.ContentTypeBeginsWithId = Constants.ContentTypes.Base.xxxDocument.ID;
                                cqwp.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                                cqwp.Title = "Recent Documents";
                                string query = @"<Where>" +
                                                    "<BeginsWith>" +
                                                        "<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>" +
                                                            "<Value Type='Text'>" + Constants.ContentTypes.Base.document.ID + "</Value>" +
                                                    "</BeginsWith>" +
                                                "</Where>" +
                                                "<OrderBy> " +
                                                    "<FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='FALSE'/> " +
                                                "</OrderBy>";
                                cqwp.QueryOverride = query;
                                cqwp.ItemLimit = 10;
                                cqwp.ListsOverride = "<Lists ServerTemplate='101'/>";
                                cqwp.WebsOverride = "<Webs Recursive='False' />";

                                cqwp.MainXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl");
                                cqwp.HeaderXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl");
                                cqwp.ItemXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl");

                                cqwp.CommonViewFields = "Name, Text; Modified, DateTime";

                                mgrPageManager.AddWebPart(cqwp, "Footer", 0);
                                mgrPageManager.SaveChanges(cqwp);
                            #endregion
```

Comment: What do you mean with "When I go to design view, the type is Assets Library instead of Document Library"? The asset library is a form of Document Library (base type is 1)

Comment: When you edit the page, and check the web part properties, Asset Library is selected, instead of Document Library,  when asset library is selected, the cqwp does not return anything, if I select document library then it works fine.   Obviously something should be wrong with the code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Content Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.aspx) web part [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.basetype.aspx) and [ServerTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.servertemplate.aspx) properties are interchangeable, they could not be specified both at the same time. 
When the BaseType property is specified, the  [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistqueryinfo.lists.aspx) property for [CrossListQueryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistqueryinfo.aspx) is generated like this:

```
<Lists BaseType="{BaseType}">
```

otherwise it is generated based on [ServerTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.servertemplate.aspx) property

```
<Lists ServerTemplate="{ServerTemplate}">
```

if [ListsOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.listsoverride.aspx) property is not specified.

---

In your case there is no need to specify BaseType property because ListsOverride property is already provided.